# SQL select group if group have some row

Tags: sql

I have a table `users`:

```
user_id   site       event    date
---------------------------------
ITB001    A          open     01-15
ITB001    A          open     02-15
ITB001    A          close    03-15
ITB001    B          open     02-15
ITB001    B          open     01-15 
MKB114    A          open     04-15
MKB114    A          close    05-15
```

I want to get group in table.

Only if group have row with event=close and date=03-15 for this example this table

```
user_id   site    sum_event   
---------------------------
ITB001    A       3
```

Is there a simple way to get this? Without large string query?

And which very fast query?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    U1.user_id,
    U1.site,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Users U1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Users U2
        WHERE
           U2.user_id = U1.user_id AND
           U2.site = U1.site AND
           U2.[date] = '03-15'
    )
GROUP BY
    U1.user_id,
    U1.site
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic aggregation query with a `having` clause.  Here is one method:

```
select user_id, site, count(*)
from users u
group by user_id site
having sum(case when event = 'close' and date = '03-15' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```